# How to processes remaining payload when the handler get timeout in AWS lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-3.6, python-3.7, aws-serverless

I am trying to transform data from CSV to JSON in AWS lambda (using Python 3). The size of file is 65 MB, so its getting timeout before completing the process and the entire execution get fails.

I would need to know how I can handle such a case where AWS Lambda should able to process a maximum set of data within the time out period and the remaining  payload should keep into an S3 bucket.

### Below is the transformation code

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
import os
json_content = {}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_source = boto3.resource('s3')
    if event:
        fileObj=event['Records'][0]
        fileName=str(fileObj['s3']['object']['key'])
        eventTime =fileObj['eventTime']    
        fileObject= s3_source.Object('inputs3', fileName)
        data = fileObject.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig').split()
        arr=[]
        csvreader= csv.DictReader(data)
        newFile=getFile_extensionName(fileName,extension_type)
        for row in csvreader:
            arr.append(dict(row))
        json_content['Employees']=arr
        print("Json Content is",json_content)
        s3_source.Object('s3-output', "output.json").put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(json_content).encode('utf-8-sig'))))
        print("File Uploaded")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'fileObject':eventTime,
     }
```

### AWS Lambda function configuration:

Memory: 640 MB

Timeout: 15 min

Comment: Is you AWS Lambda function invoked sychronously or asynchronously? What's the timeout set for your function? Is the transformation performance limited by available CPU performance? How does your transformation code look like?

Comment: AWS Lambda has a maximum timeout of 15 minutes, in 65 MB of files how many rows are you processing? If you can post your code there might be some optimization we can try in that as well.

Comment: Hi @Dunedan and Hussain, I have update with code and other details.. Its a basic csv to json transformation.. Can you please have look

Comment: Can you provide the log messages execution of this AWS Lambda function produces? Does the problem go away if you increase the available memory to something like 1792MB?

Comment: Hi @Dunedan .. here is the log from the lambda execution
### REPORT RequestId: 53abacf2-8484-2342347 Duration: 723205.42 ms Billed Duration: 723300 ms Memory Size: 1792 MB Max Memory Used: 1792 MB Init Duration: 252.77 ms

RequestId: 53abacf2-848431312312 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed
Runtime.ExitError

Comment: Your problem definitely isn't a timeout, as your function execution fails after 252ms, while the timeout is much higher. What's printed between the START and REPORT lines in the log?

Comment: I misread the duration. It's apparently 723 seconds, so quite a bit longer, but still no timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Since your function is timing-out, you only have two options:

1. **Increase the amount of assigned memory**. This will also increase the amount of CPU assigned to the function, so it *should* run faster. However, this might not be enough to avoid the timeout.

or

2. **Don't use AWS Lambda**.

The most common use-case for AWS Lambda functions is for small microservices, sometimes only running for a few seconds or even a fraction of a second.

If your use-case runs for over 15 minutes, then it probably isn't a good candidate for AWS Lambda.

You can look at alternatives such as running your code on an Amazon EC2 instance or using a Fargate container.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is running out of memory:

```
Memory Size: 1792 MB Max Memory Used: 1792
```

Also, it only ran for 12 minutes:

```
Duration: 723205.42 ms
```

(723 seconds ≈ 12 minutes)

Therefore, you should either:

- **Increase memory** (but this costs more), *or*
- Change your program so that, instead of accumulating the JSON string in memory, you continually write it out to a local disk file to `/tmp/` and then upload the resulting file to Amazon S3

However, the maximum disk storage space provided to an AWS Lambda function is 512MB and it appears that your output file is bigger than this. Therefore, increasing memory would be the only option. The increased expense related to assigning more resources to the Lambda function suggests that you might be better-off using EC2 or Fargate rather than Lambda.